# How to remove single or doable word form list in python and pdfminer unable to covert rupee font

Tags: python, list

I am extracting text from PDF by converted into HTML. when we extracting text form Html with the help of BeautifulSoup. I have faced issues with symbols like currency (rupee symbol).and the rupees symbol came like a Tilda ['``']

['Amid ', '41'], ['``', '41'], ['3L cr shortfall, GST cess to continue beyond June 2022 ', '41'], ['Cong clips wings of �letter writers� in new appointments  ', '32'] ,['MVA aims to cut guv�s power to choose VCs ', '28']}

Present output

```
  1. Amid 
    2. 3L cr shortfall, GST cess to continue beyond June 2022 
    3. Cong clips wings of ‘letter writers’ in new appointments  
    4. MVA aims to cut guv’s power to choose VC
```

I want the output of text which has a higher font size and also want to remove single line character in a list like [['``', '41']

> My desired output should look like this

```
 1. Amid  3L cr shortfall, GST cess to continue beyond June 2022 
 2. Cong clips wings of ‘letter writers’ in new appointments 
 3. Cong clips wings of ‘letter writers’ in new appointments
```

> My full Code:

```
import sys,os,re,operator,tempfile,fileinput
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Tag,UnicodeDammit
from io import  StringIO
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text_to_fp

def convert_html(filename):
    output = StringIO()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
        extract_text_to_fp(fin, output, laparams=LAParams(),output_type='html', codec=None)
        Out_txt=output.getvalue()
        return Out_txt

def get_the_start_of_font(x,attr):
    """ Return the index of the 'font-size' first occurrence or None. """
    match = re.search(x, attr)
    if match is not None:
        return match.start()
    return None 

def get_font_size_from(attr):
    """ Return the font size as string or None if not found. """
    font_start_i = get_the_start_of_font('font-size:',attr)
    if font_start_i is not None:
        font_size=str(attr[font_start_i + len('font-size:'):].split('px')[0])
        if int(font_size)>25:
            return font_size
    return None
def write_to_txtfile(PDF_file,x):
    filename='txt'.join(PDF_file.split('pdf'))
    path_out=(r'c:\Headline\out\\')
    
    with open(path_out+filename,'w+',encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
        top3=x[:4]
        for idx, line in enumerate(sorted([row for row in top3 if len(row[0]) > 2], key=lambda z: int(z[1]), reverse=True)):
           text_file.write("{}. {}\n".format(idx+1, line[0]))
             
    
def main():
    os.chdir(r'c:\Headline\in')
    for PDF_file in os.listdir():
        if PDF_file.endswith('.pdf'):
            raw_html=convert_html(PDF_file)
            #Converting Microsoft smart quotes to HTML or XML entities:
            UnicodeDammit(raw_html, ["windows-1252"], smart_quotes_to="html").unicode_markup 
            soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
        
            # iterate through all descendants:
            fonts = []
            for child in soup.descendants:
                if isinstance(child, Tag) is True and child.get('style') is not None:
                    font = get_font_size_from(child.get('style'))
                    if font is not None:
                        fonts.append([str(child.text.replace('\n',' ')),font])
                  
            write_to_txtfile(PDF_file,fonts)
        
            print(" File have Sucess of Extract Headline form this Page%s"%PDF_file )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
headlines = [['In bid to boost realty, state cuts stamp duty for 7 mths ', '42'],
             ['India sees world’s third-biggest spike of 76,000+ cases, toll crosses 60k ','28'],
             ['O', '33'],
             ['Don’t hide behind RBI on loan interest waiver: SC to govt ', '28']]

for idx, line in enumerate(sorted([row for row in headlines if len(row[0]) > 1], key=lambda z: int(z[1]), reverse=True)):
    print("{}. {}".format(idx+1, line[0]))
```

Output:

```
1. In bid to boost realty, state cuts stamp duty for 7 mths
2. India sees world’s third-biggest spike of 76,000+ cases, toll crosses 60k
3. Don’t hide behind RBI on loan interest waiver: SC to govt
```

---

Breakdown of what is happening above:

`[row for row in headlines if len(row[0]) > 1]`

This will create a new list, containing all entries in `headlines` if the length of `entry_in_headlines[0]` is greater than 1.

`sorted(<iterable>, key=lambda z: int(z[1]), reverse=True)`

Will sort the given iterable using a lambda function, which takes one argument, and returns the second index of that variable as an integer. Then reverses the results, due to `reverse=True`.

`for idx, line in enumerate(<iterable>):`

Looping over [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) will return both the "count" of how many times it has been called, and also the next value inside of the iterable.

`print("{}. {}".format(idx+1, line[0]))`

Using string-formatting we create the new string inside of the for-loop.

Comment: I am unable to convert Indian rupees form pdf get below output
1. Amid 
2. ``
3. 3L cr shortfall, GST cess to continue beyond June 2022

Answer (score 1):

i can't really work out what you are trying or where your data is but you need to add an if statement.

For example:

```
data = ['In bid to boost realty, state cuts stamp duty for 7 mths ', '42']
if len(data[0].split()) >= 2:
    print(data[0])
```

Any statements with 2 words or less will not be printed.

If you have a list of lists:

```
data = [['In bid to boost realty, state cuts stamp duty for 7 mths ', '42'], 
['India sees world’s third-biggest spike of 76,000+ cases, toll crosses 60k',                                                                           
'28'], ['O', '33'], ['Don’t hide behind RBI on loan interest waiver: SC to 
govt ', '28']]

for lists in data:
    if len(lists[0].split()) <= 2:
        data.remove(lists)

print(*("".join(lists[0]) for lists in data), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to get Top 3 headlines from newspaper PDF  which has higher font size. First I convert PDF into HTML by pdfminer and then in a text file.

Comment: Ok so wherever you have your lists of headlines and font sizes pass them through the if statement first and then sort via font size.

Comment: Error list' object has no attribute 'split' while applying if

Comment: See edit. You should be able to modify your code using that. Try running what i posted to see what the output is

Comment: See Edit. I have posted full code. still getting an error while applying your code

Comment: The main goal is archive Top 3 Headlines in below form in a text file 
1.'headlinline 
2. headlining 
3.headlinline